# How do I sort items that are grouped

Tags: grouping, sorting

I have a view setup were "call sign 1" is grouped and then grouped by "Call sign 2". This allows me to see when mutable submissions of the call sign have been submitted to my custom list. However, I really only care if there are more than one submission that links two call signs to each other. How do I get the view to only show groups of 2 or more?

If this is not possible is there at least a way to sort them were call signs that have the most submissions show at the top of my view?

[image]

Comment: Which version of SharePoint? There are things would could do with older versions and SharePoint Designer that we cannot do with newer versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go in Modify View and check the settings under **Group By** - try changing it to descending and see what happens. [image: grouped by sort]

When you are using Group By it overrides the usual Sort By settings.  BTW - I'm using SP2013.

As for sorting by the grouping with the most items under it, you could create a new column which counts items in that grouping - you could use a calculated column for this.  Once you have a value in the new column you can configure the view to sort by the NewColumn value in descending order.

You might be able to filter out any groupings that have less than 2 by filtering on NewColumn `not less than 2`.

Comment: I'm using SP2013 BTW. I don't have any experience using calculated columns. How would that work?

Comment: Try googling calculated columns for Sharepoint or have a look on the marvellous SPSE site - it's a treasure trove of information.  Try looking at the calculated columns tag for a start: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculated-column?tab=Newest

Comment: I think my question now is what would the formula in a calculated column, were I want to count the number of times a single line of text is entered into my list? Your advice got me the rest of the way to my goal, just need this last bit of help. Thank you!

Comment: Hmm, I've been mulling this over and spent 15 minutes experimenting before i finished work yesterday, but didn't crack it.  I think you could post a new question on this one, specifically asking how to: 1. Count # of values that are the same and 2. How to then filter out anything that there are less than 2 of.  BTW - like many users on this site, I obsessively collect points, so don't forget to upvote Answers (or even Accept answers) if it's been useful...hint hint :)